# Advanced vegetation index for Sentinel 2

Tags: google-earth-engine, sentinel-2

How is advanced vegetation index (AVI) calculated for Sentinel 2 imagery in Google Earth Engine? The following doesn't look quite right:

```
var s2 = ee.Image('COPERNICUS/S2_SR/20200101T100319_20200101T100321_T32TQM')

var avi_int = s2.expression('(nir)*(1+red)*(nir - red)', {
  'nir': s2.select('B8'),
  'red': s2.select('B4'),
})
var avi = avi_int.pow(1 / 3)

Map.addLayer(s2, {bands: 'B4,B3,B2', max: 3000, gamma: 1.5}, 'rgb')
Map.addLayer(avi, {max: 10000, palette: 'red,yellow,green'}, 'avi')
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/c4312141452cbb655db6dbf250218c65

Answer (score 1):

Your expression should have `1 - red` instead of `1 + red`. Well, since Sentinel 2 imagery in EE has been scaled by `10000`, it actually should say `10000 - red`. AVI should also be `0` when `nir < red`.

```
var image = ee.Image('COPERNICUS/S2_SR/20200101T100319_20200101T100321_T32TQM')
  .select(
      ['B2', 'B3', 'B4', 'B8'], 
      ['blue', 'green', 'red', 'nir']
  )

var avi = image
  .expression('i.nir * (10000 - i.red) * (i.nir - i.red)', {i: image})
  .pow(1/3)
  .where(image.expression('i.nir - i.red < 0', {i: image}), 0)
  .uint16()

Map.addLayer(image, {bands: 'red,green,blue', max: 3000, gamma: 1.5}, 'rgb')
Map.addLayer(avi, {min: 0, max: 6500, palette: 'red,yellow,green'}, 'avi')
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/8fa6190f02dd334db275f4a1891622f3

Comment: explain the value of gamma, how it identify

Comment: It just makes the image brighter - it’s purely for visualization.

Comment: Sir, I am a beginner in the gee so I want to know about all the parameters. also, sir clarify maximum and minimum value how to identify

Comment: sir above two codes which one suitable and useful.

Comment: You can read about the visualization parameters here: https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/image_visualization

Comment: To find out about reasonable min/max values, you can use the layer manager: https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/playground#layer-manager